# how do I assert that a function was called?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

I have a Goat class:

```
class Goat
  constructor: (@headbutt) -> 
    @isCranky = true

  approach: -> 
    if @isCranky
      @headbutt()
```

I'd like to write a Mocha test to assert that headbutt() was called if isCranky is true and approach is called.

The only explanation I can find for this is in Ruby. Tried translating it, but failed. How can I assert that the correct function was called? I think I can solve it in a hacky way, but would rather learn the right way. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
describe 'Goat', ->
  it 'should call headbutt when approached', ->
    headbuttCalled = no
    headbutt = -> headbuttCalled = true
    goat = new Goat headbutt

    goat.approach()

    assert headbuttCalled
```

If you find yourself repeating many times this pattern of testing whether a function was called, you'd probably want to use something like [SinonJS](http://sinonjs.org/), which provides a "spy" construct:

```
headbutt = sinon.spy()
goat = new Goat headbutt

goat.approach()

assert headbutt.called
```

Comment: @IsaacCambron With SimonJS the code gets more elegant, yes. But this is a very simple example, and i think including a whole library for what can be done with a simple extra line of code is not worthwhile. Besides, i think it's valuable to understand how things like SimonJS do the "magic" they do :)

Comment: Good answer thanks. My hacky answer was very similar to what you wrote and I'm sure I'll have more places to assert that f(x) was called, so Sinon looks like a good choice.

Comment: It's actually SinonJS, not SimonJS